# Splitting and organizing my website

Tags: html

Okay, so I'm making my own little archive for music and such, and I'm kind of having issues figuring this out.

[image]

What I'd like to do is get the fourth table there underneath the 3rd one, leave the right side empty, then make another table under the empty side. I'd like the titles and such (which are completely separate from the info table, just above) to always be on the left side, that that way if I end up with 3, 5, etc. it'll make it rather simple. I have an idea on how I could do it, but I'd like for it to be more clean and easier.

Since I can't post a picture, there's just a simple link.

Comment: Have you thought about using `css` `floats`?

Comment: That's actually what I did and it did not work.

Comment: Floats will mostly always work, its probably just wrong ;) could you post the full code?

Comment: #left-side{
 float:left;
 width:50%; 
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;
 
 
}
#left-side TD{
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;vertical-align: top;color:#8F8E89;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}
#right-side{
 float:right;
 width:50%; 
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;
 
 
}
#right-side TD{
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:10px;vertical-align: top;color:#8F8E89;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're using css float, what you're missing is a clear.

Add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after each row. If you're using a css library it'll probably have a clearfix, in which case try `<div class="clearfix"></div>`.

Comment: @Brujeria, if that's the case then you want to press the checkmark on the left of my answer. It lets people know your question was resolved, how it was resolved, and that you actually follow up on your questions. Some people get a little grumpy when a person asks a lot of questions but don't use this feature.